# Skip test steps in cypress cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

lets say the test scenario is

```
Scenario : validate user details 
Given : land on home page 
And : find a user 
And: click on user name
Then : verify user details are shown
```

Here in the **find a user** step, there may or may not be any users. If there are any users present then only I need to perform step 4 and 5 else I need to mark the scenario as passed and skip steps4,5

any suggesstions is greatly appreciated,thanks

Comment: That seems like a pretty useless test - If you don't have any users, don't use that condition. If you want to test the user name, ***make sure there are users***.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this testcase as

```
Scenario Outline : validate user details 
Given : land on home page 
And :Find user "<user>" and verify its details
Examples:
|user|
|user123|
```

In "And" statement you can can apply check that if user exist then verify it's detail otherwise move to next step.
**for example** check that if any id or class exist on DOM in which user detail is written if id or class is not visible then skip